# jquery setting div content from a form

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a field to fill in email along with other inputs that output to a image on the page displaying the user input.  When they fill in the email field we want the div for the email to show what they entered and the div above to show "Email:"  If they change their mind and clear the email field the email div clears correctly but the div above remains saying "Email:"  I am not sure why the second field will not clear when it is empty?

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#email").change(function () {
    var src = $(this).val();
    $("#emailaddy").html($(this).val());
    if ($("#email").val() != ''){
         $("#email1").html("Email:"); }
});
});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Comment: Can you show some HTML?

Comment: FYI `$(function(){` and `$(document).ready(function () {` are redundant.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tNszf/ (_edit: matches the answer by @Smorko_) and see if it helps. Please provide an online example the next time, for example on http://jsfiddle.net/, http://codepen.io or http://jsbin.com/

Comment: Whoops, sorry @Simeon Nenov – somehow missed your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function()
  {
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#email").change(function () {
    var src = $(this).val();
    $("#emailaddy").html($(this).val());
        if ($("#email").val() != ''){
             $("#email1").html("Email:"); 
        }
        else
        {
            $("#email1").html(""); 
        }
        });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect...  Duh to me....  hhahah  Thanks, I need coffee!

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the html content for your "email1" div. Set:

```
    if ($("#email").val() != '') {
      $("#email1").html("Email:"); 
    } else {
      $("#email1").html("");
    }
```